# The effect of concentric contraction and eccentric contraction on muscles

Tags: physical-therapy

I'm a premed student, and I was trying to understand how concentric and eccentric contraction can induce injury or muscle growth, and how an injured muscle responds to those contractions.

What I got is that concentric contractions create microtears, but muscle strains come from eccentric contraction. I understand how lengthening can cause strain, but I do not understand why shortening creates tears. Can somebody explain this process in detail? Also, is the overuse injury referring to too many microtears?

If a muscle is injured from a strain, that means it's torn in an eccentric contraction (see ref [here](https://journals.physiology.org/doi/full/10.1152/japplphysiol.00971.2016)). Does this mean that we would always be testing for an acute injury with eccentric contractions? When would concentric contractions with resistance be useful for testing?

Appreciate your help,
Jingxuan

Comment: 1. I'm sorry if the last statement sounds bold. It rather stems from my personal understanding of how muscles work, and it may be corrected. I value my reasoning more than I do sources. However, the statement is supported by this article:https://journals.physiology.org/doi/full/10.1152/japplphysiol.00971.2016#:~:text=concentric%20(i.e.%2C%20shortening)%20muscle,at%20low%20intensity%20(15).    \n sd

Comment: 2. To my understanding, if eccentric contraction causes the strain, then further eccentric contraction will tear the strain more, causing pain.  Concentric contraction shouldn't do the same.

Comment: Okay, now you just need to [edit] your question and add the link and quote the text the link points to. Everything needs to be in the question itself, not in comments.